# assign memory resources to a running pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

i would want to know how can i assign memory resources to a running pod ?

i tried `kubectl get po foo-7d7dbb4fcd-82xfr  -o yaml > pod.yaml`
but when i run the command `kubectl apply -f pod.yaml`

```
 The Pod "foo-7d7dbb4fcd-82xfr" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pod is the minimal kubernetes resources, and it doesn't not support editing as you want to do.

I suggest you to use [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) to run your pod, since it is a "pod manager" where you have a lot of additional features, like pod self-healing, pod liveness/readness etc...

You can define the resources in your deployment file like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo
        image: mendhak/http-https-echo
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 15m
            memory: 100Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 15m
            memory: 100Mi 
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

As @KoopaKiller mentioned, you can't update `spec.containers.resources` field, this is mentioned in [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#container-v1-core) object spec:

> Compute Resources required by this container. Cannot be updated.

Instead you can deploy your Pods using [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) object. In that case if you change resources config for your Pods, deployment controller will roll out updated versions of your Pods.